# Kotlin: define LongArray to Notification.Builder.setVibrate(LONG_ARRAY)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I'm using Kotlin and want to set vibrate for a notification.
The `.setVibrate()` function need a `LongArray` but i cant define for it.

```
var Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,R.string.channel_name.toString())
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("my notification Title")
        .setContentText("somthing else for content")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setVibrate(LONG_ARRAY)
```

I was search in web but just find solution for java. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.setVibrate(longArrayOf(1L, 2L, 3L))
```

will work just fine, or

```
.setVibrate(listOf(1L, 2L, 3L).toLongArray())
```

if you really wanted.

Comment: made an edit, I just find this more readable, feel free to rollback if you don't agree :D